# Node.js read TCPSocket and write to a variable

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp

I've got a litte problem with my code snipet. I wrote a example to learn the TCP Socket Communication for a project. For the moment i can send a TCP Socket and read the answer, but i want to use the answer in other software parts. For that i tried to use the variable socketmessage but this doesn't work. Does anyone have the answer for my problem? Thanks a lot

```
var net = require('net');
var client = new net.Socket();
var HOST='127.0.0.1';
var PORT='20000';

var MSG="{\"REQUEST\":\"STATUS\"}";    
var socketmessage;

socketmessage=getSocketMessage(MSG);
console.log ("Socket Message: " + socketmessage);

function getSocketMessage(tcpmsg){
  var outData;

  client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log("Client: " + tcpmsg);
    client.write(tcpmsg);
  });

  client.setTimeout(5000, function() {  client.destroy(); });

  client.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('Server: ' + data);
    outData = data.toString('utf8');
    console.log ("Socketmessage: " + outData);
    client.destroy();
  });

  //Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
  client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
  });

  // Add a 'error' event handler for the client socket
  client.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Error Connection: ' + error);
  });

  return outData;
}
```

Terminal:
Socket Message: undefined
Client: {"REQUEST":"STATUS"}
Server: {"STATUS":0.000000}

Answer (score 2):

This is because function `getSocketMessage` is asynchronous. You are trying to return the received message. The function returns immediately, `outData` being undefined then. Its value is 
set when data arrives from server. The network I/O is evented, the event you use is `data`

```
client.on('data', function(data) {
```

The received message can only be handled properly inside the event-handler for `data`. You would have to call your other part from here itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a read stream and once the stream ends you may process the data.

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream(path of the file, 'utf8'); //you can use path.join(loc, filename)
 var data = '';
 readStream.on('data', function(chunk:any) {              
                data += chunk;
              }).on('end', function() {
                let gotContent = data.toString(); //
                doWhatEver(gotContent)  //the method is async or promose
              then(function(result){
                console.log(result); //desired output
              })

  });
```